# How can I pass spring application.yaml file to spring context created in Java project using spring boot project as dependency?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, configuration, configuration-files

I am using spring boot project as a dependency in another non spring java project. The problem is I am getting error when spring processes @Value() annotation.

According to [this article](https://www.javaguides.net/2019/02/spring-applicationcontext-example.html)
In order to get instances of the beans managed in spring I created `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` and created applicationcontext.xml,

but I am getting error from @Value("${proper}") anotation that

`the resource cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist`

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[] {"spring-application.xml"});

context.getBean("mybean");
```

applicationcontext.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.example" />

</beans>
```

The application.yaml is located outside the project in `/opt/myapp/config/application.yaml` and contains:

```
proper: file:/path/to/some/file/that/exists
```

I am expecting that spring will initialize the value of `proper` in component using the default application.yaml. since I can run spring boot project stand alone and it works fine.

Any Ideas?

Comment: where the file that you mentioned in "proper" property resides? If its is classpath then try with proper: classpath:/path/to/some/file/that/exists

Comment: I was using external spring configuration  resides in /opt/myapp/config/application.yaml but even if I put application.yaml in the resources in side my spring project, I get the same error

Comment: I was not talking about application.yml I was taking about the file that you are referring in "proper" property

Comment: sorry... proper is a file on my pc not in class path